# Pass a server side parameter to AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I need to pass a variable from the server side to AngularJS.

I have the following HTML on the server side

```
<div ng-app="tablesApp" ng-controller="tablesCtrl" ng-init="lang='@lang';...go();" ...>
    <st-date-range ?lang="@lang"? ...> </st-date-range>
...
</div>
```

I should put somewhere in the HTML code (actually in `ng-init`, but if there are other options I'm OK with that) my server side `@lang` value, then Angular should use that value...

I use a directive and I would like to pass the `@lang`(a server side ASP.NET razor variable) param to angular in order to use it in the template path:

```
app.directive('stDateRange', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^stTable',
        templateUrl: '/templates/stDateRange.en.html',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            var tableState = ctrl.tableState();
            scope.$watchGroup(["minDate", "maxDate"],
                function (newValues, oldValues) {
```

so, my server side `@lang` param I would like to pass to the directive in order to use it in the template URL, like this:

```
templateUrl: '/templates/stDateRange.@(lang).html'
```

#### P.S.:

I'll take [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/brZMrv) to show my need:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('testDirective', function(){
  var lang = 'en'; // <<< Set the variable HERE << !!!
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   template: '<p>my lang  is "<strong>'+lang+'</strong>" </p>'
  };  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="app" ng-init="lang='fr'">
  <h3>Test directive for 'fr' lang</h3>
  <test-directive></test-directive>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to create *dynamic* `templateUrl` based on `attr.lang`.

So I would write your directive as:

```
app.directive('stDateRange', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^stTable',
        template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

         scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
           var url = '/templates/stDateRange.' + attrs.lang + '.html' 
           return url;
         };

            var tableState = ctrl.tableState();
            scope.$watchGroup(["minDate", "maxDate"],
                function (newValues, oldValues) {
```

And HTML call:

```
<test-directive lang="{{lang}}"></test-directive>
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X7G1fuOdJBBcQO3mhk2r?p=preview)</kbd>

---

**[Edit 1]**

If you don't want to use link, you can load `constant`:

```
app.directive('testDirective', function(Constants){
  var lang = Constants.val;
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   template: '<p>my lang  is "<strong>'+lang+'</strong>" </p>'
  };  
});

app.constant('Constants', {
    val: 'Fess'
});
```

<kbd>[Demo Codepen](https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/qXvKXP)</kbd>

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! I updated the OP with a codepen sample to be more specific...

Comment: @Serge take a look on demo I posted

Comment: I see... I wonder however if it's possible *in example I posted* to modify directly in the directive `var lang = 'en';` => `var lang = myLangParam;`

Comment: @Serge in your demo you try to modify static HTML but in question you posted you work with html file\

Comment: I just try to pass the `@lang` to the directive code *directly*, not in the `link` function, if possible

Comment: @Serge what about constant? pls check 2n demo

Comment: maybe, but the question is now how I modify that "constant" via my server-side `@lang` variable ? because the server side code `@lang` variable may change if the user selects another GUI language...

Comment: normally I put somewhere in the HTML code (actually in `ng-init`) my server side value, Angular use that value... I should pass it from the server to the client in a way...

Comment: @Serge so why my 1st demo doesn't good for u? it takes value from in-init without any controller

Comment: mainly, your 1st demo is OK for me, I just wonder if is there a way to modify the param directly in the directive code, and not in the LINK function

Comment: From my exp. its not possible to do that by angular way.

Comment: OK, now I am happy that I could explain better my question :)  Thanks ! if no one suggest another way, I'll take your dynamic template way !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$scope` on your application directive `ng-app` but you can use `$rootScope`. I would achieve this by parsing `$root.language` into your directive and finally load the template dynamically. You could also access `$rootScope.language` inside your directive directly without parsing `$root.language` into it. You can do as you wish - **[demo punkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JmQw873E3hZmRNsot2fD?p=preview)**.

#### AngularJS application:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {}); 


app.directive('test', function ($http, $compile) {
  return {
        scope: {
          lang: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $http.get('./template.'+ scope.lang +'.html').then(function (result) {
              scope.test = 'some test';
              element.html(result.data);
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

#### View:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" ng-init="language = 'en'">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <test lang="$root.language"></test>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## Template which includes your server side param:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" ng-init="language = '@lang'">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <test lang="$root.language"></test>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass the param early in the directive function, like in the codepen I updated the OP?

Comment: @Serge Yea no, while `ng-app` is a application directive it does not support `scopes` / `e2e binding` -> this is not possible. I updated my answer and included an `ApplicationController`. This should help ya.

Comment: @Serge btw. why do you need to define the language with `ng-init` inside the view?

Comment: `You need a controller to make that work. ` why not?  it will be stored under rootScope. Please check my demo in PLunker

Comment: @Serge I just updated this answer. This should match to all your requirements. Thanks Maxim+